# cross join in sqlalchemy 1.3

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I can't understand how to connect two tables with cross join.
Earler, at sqlalchemy version 1.1.4 I do it this way:

```
A = Table1.sa 
B = Table2.sa
my_query = A.query().join(B, literal(True))
```

But after updating to version 1.3 it's raise exception:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't determine which FROM clause to join from, there are multiple FROMS which can join to this entity. Try adding an explicit ON clause to help resolve the ambiguity.

I'm understand that it's mean that I have to do something like that:

```
my_query = A.query().join(B, A.fireign_key_id = B.id)
```

But table A haven't foreign key to table B.

How to connect two tables with cross join and without foreign key?
Thanks.

Comment: Please add definitions for models `A` and `B`, or `Table1.sa` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for all answers. Exception was raise, because the query couldn't determine which table is left and into query(...) use the fields of table B. After I explicitly indicated the left table, this exception disappeared.

```
my_query = A.query(...).join(B, A.id != None)
```

Comment: If you also need the data from the other table, you may need to do something like `.with_entities(A, B.columns.some_column)`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do a cross join is to select from both tables without providing any filter to perform an ANSI join:

```
my_query = session.query(A, B)
```

This'll produce a cartesian product (cross join) of your A and B entities, no workarounds required.

Answer (score 1):

Cross join doesn't use join conditions so there can't be any ON between the `Table1` and `Table2`. In Cross join each row from `T1` joins with all rows from `T2`. Are you sure about using Cross join?

Comment: `JOIN foo ON true` is effectively a cross join, though not written explicitly as one.

Comment: The cross join does not itself apply any predicate to filter rows from the joined table. The results of a cross join can be filtered by using a WHERE clause which may then produce the equivalent of an inner join. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join  Ok, we also can use ON instead of WHERE and result will be the same, but for what?

Comment: Please note the word "effectively". The result of the aforementioned inner join is exactly equal to the relation produced by a cross join, and the result can be further selected from using a `WHERE` clause just as well. On the other hand the simple approach would be to just list the FROM-items in pre SQL-92 style.